# Mesh apply data applies a different information

Tags: mesh, error, mixamo

I have been trying to export a mesh into Mixamo, but when I click on Apply Data function, it drastically changes my mesh and I don't know why or how to solve it. It appears that the problem is only on scale. Could anybody help me with that?

[image: Without applying]

[image: Applying the "Apply Data" option]